# How to obtain route information in angular from url string

Tags: angularjs

Anyone knows if there is a tool (or a built-in feature) in `angular` to obtain a route object from an `url` string?

Example

I set up route navigation like this:

```js
$routeProvider
  .when('/users/:id', 
    {
      templateUrl: 'components/users/edit.html',
      controller: 'UsersCtrl',
      access: {
        requiresLogin: true,
        roles: ['Admin']
      }
    });
```

I do have a string like `/users/2` and i want to be able to obtain the route object asociated with that string, the object containing `templateUrl`, `controller` and `access properties`.

I can see all the routes defined in `$route.routes`, but the routes there are in the format `/users/:id`, so I would have to resolve the `url` manually.

The purpose of this is to secure `ui-elements` (using a `directive`) based on route navigation (like spring security with authorize tags)

I do have a `directive` called `navigate-to`, that `directive` allows me to use `buttons` just like an `anchor`

```html
<button navigate-to="/users/{{user.id}}">Edit</button>
```

And I want to determine if the current user is allowed to navigate to the target `url` (without actually navigating to it).

I can protect navigation with the `$routeChangeStart` event, what I need is to access the route information (to perform security checks) before routing.

**SOLVED:**
I have found the way (looking at $route source code) to match the url and obtain the route object (manually), not ideal but it works. Here is the function to get the route information:

```
                var getRouteInfo = function(path) {
                var matched = false,
                    matchedRoute = null;
                angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route) {
                    if (!route.regexp) return;
                    if (!matched && route.regexp.exec(path)) {
                        matched = true;
                        matchedRoute = route;
                    }
                });
                return matchedRoute;
            };
```

Comment: Did you try to use `$routeParams` to catch the param string?

Comment: I don't need the current parameters, and I don't see anything useful in `$routeParams` on the docs. I want to get the next route object (before calling `$location.path(nextUrl)`), i know how to obtain the route object once i navigate to the url or while the routing is being made.

Comment: i can only recomment $stateProvider its pretty much the same design as Route but with $state u can read everything everywhere

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: Thanks to @stackg91 for the suggestion, i was reading about `angular-ui-router` and it seems that i'll be able to do what i want using that framework to handle routes. But i can't switch the behavior of the entire application right now, all my routing is based on `$routeProvider`